# How to set mapKeyDotReplacement for MongoDbMessageStore.MessageReadingMongoConverter

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm using `MongoDbMessageStore` to store incoming AMQP messages. The messages have headers whose keys contain dots. When a message is about to be persisted in MongoDB, an exception is thrown:

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: Map key lnu_ocr_core.ocr.rabbitmq_ver contains dots but no replacement was configured! Make sure map keys don't contain dots in the first place or configure an appropriate replacement!
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.potentiallyEscapeMapKey(MappingMongoConverter.java:714)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.prepareMapKey(MappingMongoConverter.java:696)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeMapInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:663)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.createMap(MappingMongoConverter.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writePropertyInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:478)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:437)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(MappingMongoConverter.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:330)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:425)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.writeInternal(MappingMongoConverter.java:399)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.write(MappingMongoConverter.java:363)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore$MessageReadingMongoConverter.write(MongoDbMessageStore.java:530)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore$MessageReadingMongoConverter.write(MongoDbMessageStore.java:497)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.toDbObject(MongoTemplate.java:873)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.doInsert(MongoTemplate.java:855)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.insert(MongoTemplate.java:799)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore.addMessageDocument(MongoDbMessageStore.java:228)
    at org.springframework.integration.mongodb.store.MongoDbMessageStore.addMessagesToGroup(MongoDbMessageStore.java:303)
    at org.springframework.integration.store.AbstractMessageGroupStore.addMessageToGroup(AbstractMessageGroupStore.java:209)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.store(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:621)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:413)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
    ...
```

I know that to tackle that, I would have to set `mapKeyDotReplacement` on the `MappingMongoConverter`. However, the `MongoDbMessageStore` uses a private, internally created and configured instance of `MongoDbMessageStore.MessageReadingMongoConverter`. Is there a way to set the `mapKeyDotReplacement` there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to abandon that inconvenient `MongoDbMessageStore` in favor of `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore`. Semantically they are the same and this one can be configured with external `MappingMongoConverter`:

```
public ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter) {
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/mongodb.html#mongodb-message-store